# Top questions of the week and month

Tags: discussion

When you look at the list of "top questions" for the week, does that mean the top questions asked at most 7 days from the present, or does it refer to questions asked in a certain fixed week (for example from the most recent Sunday)?

I imagine it is the former so that the list is always populated. Not that this matters all that much, I'm just curious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right, `week` = "at most 7 days from the present" and `month` = "at most 30 days from the present". At present the Month page has several questions with last activity in May. Related: [Filter top questions of the month by ...err... month?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96361/224469)

Although you did not ask about the `hot` tab, for completeness I'll add a formula for the hotness of a question, taken from [How are questions in the 'hot' tab selected?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/4766/224469) 
$$
\textrm{hotness} = \frac{ \log( 4Q_{\rm views}) + \frac15 Q_{ \#\rm answers}Q_{\rm score} + \sum A_{\rm score}}
{ Q_{\rm age}+1 - ((Q_{\rm age} - Q_{\rm updated})/2) ^{3/2}} 
$$

Comment: Very similar to the formula I used to use to compute the hotness of my dates.

Comment: @Gerry, someday I'd sure like to see that formula of yours...